# How do I format hyperlink column gridview in my codebehind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, umbraco

I am trying to make a column a hyperlink in my grid view.  I am Using Umbraco 6  childpages as datasource.  I have a link but at the moment it's going to /website/masterpages/url with %20% in the spaces

My View is like this:

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="title" datanavigateurlfields="title" headertext="Title" />
```

and code behind like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            HyperLinkField title = new HyperLinkField();
            string[] dataNavigateUrlFields = { "title" };

            title.DataTextField = "title";
            title.DataNavigateUrlFields = dataNavigateUrlFields;
           title.HeaderText = "Title";
           title.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "item.Url";

            // Create a BoundField object to display the company's city.


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("title", typeof(String)),


                            new DataColumn("lastUpdated", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("theme",typeof(string)) });


            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in uQuery.GetCurrentNode().ChildrenAsList)


            {
                var dateTimeString = item.GetProperty("lastUpdated").Value.ToString();
                var dateTime = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(dateTimeString);
               dt.Rows.Add(item.Name, dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), item.GetProperty("theme").Value.ToString());


            }

            Session["data"] = dt;
            Cache["Data"] = dt;
            Practice.DataSource = dt;
            Practice.DataBind();

        }
```

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but adding an extra column to the table called name (as this is not displayed unless you reference it on the output, removing:

```
 HyperLinkField title = new HyperLinkField();
            string[] dataNavigateUrlFields = { "title" };

            title.DataTextField = "title";
            title.DataNavigateUrlFields = dataNavigateUrlFields;
           title.HeaderText = "Title";
           title.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "item.Url";

            // Create a BoundField object to display the company's city.
```

and changing the datatextfield to "name" ie DataTextField="name".

If anyone else gets stuck:)